# Navbar appearing as transparent on mobile (Next js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, next.js

I have set my navbar go from black to transparent on large-screened devices after scrolling a certain number of pixels but have set it to always be black on mobile. However, when I deploy the website and visit it on my mobile, the navbar is transparent (without scrolling) until I go to another page.

Does anyone know how I might fix this bug?

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import window from "global";
import Link from "./Link";

export default function NavComponent(props) {

  const [navBackground, setNavBackground] = useState(false);
  const navRef = useRef();
  navRef.current = navBackground;
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const show = window.scrollY > 100;
      if (navRef.current !== show) {
        setNavBackground(show);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar
        dark
        expand="xl"
        fixed="top"
        className={styles.nav}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: `${
            navBackground || window.innerWidth < 1200 ? "black" : "transparent"
          }`,
          transition: ".2s ease",
        }}
      >
```

**EDIT:** I have fixed the problem by placing a media query (max width) for the breakpoint and set the colour as `black !important` which seemed to override the JS logic.

Comment: `window.innerWidth` is `undefined` on SSR apps. Give it some default value

Comment: I downloaded a global npm package to access the window object so it's defined. Also, it works on my computer so this doesn't explain it

Comment: You don't need package to access the window object. It is working on mobile as well as it works on your computer - it's just matter of your ternary operator

Comment: So should I replace the ternary with an if else statement? Is that your suggestion?

Comment: No, not at all. Your ternary is fine and resolves fine giving the condition `navBackground || window.innerWidth < 1200`

Comment: So why isn't my mobile understanding " window.innerWidth < 1200 "? When I use my dev tools to change my screensize on my computer it works fine. It just bugs on an actual mobile phone.

Comment: Have you tried to start your app with a screensize of a mobile device on your computer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215576/discussion-between-atman-lens-and-user0101).

Comment: what browser are you using on mobile?

Comment: Hey, both chrome and safari